# two uncountable nouns with and

Tags: grammar, differences, offensive-language, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

If we had two uncountable nouns with and , would we use a singular or plural form?

How much flour and butter is/are needed to make a pizza ?

Comment: "How much flour and butter are needed to make a pizza?" It has nothing to do with count nouns and everything to do with the enumeration of ingredients. The tip-off is the "and" between the nouns.

Comment: @Robusto Not always: 'Law and order is increasingly being used for social engineering. Charity law, for example ...' [internet] It depends on whether the elements joined by 'and' are considered cohesive enough to be considered a single concept.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, of course. "Law and order" is a more-or-less frozen trope, apprehended as a single entity. Try it on something less familiar, though: You wouldn't say "Justice and probity **is** necessary for good government." But you could definitely say "Law and order are two qualities necessary to functioning society." There are other exceptions as well, such as the names of cartoons: "*Tom and Jerry* is a cartoon people love to watch." And so on.

Comment: ...Just addressing all [I hope] aspects of: _If we had two uncountable nouns with 'and', would we use a singular or plural form?_

Answer (score 3):

> How much flour is needed?

> How much butter is needed?

> How much flour AND butter ARE needed?

> How much of the flour and butter mixture is needed?

There are two things being measured so it is, in fact, plural and needs your plural to-be verb.

Comment: What if the flour and butter are already in a single blob?

Comment: Then it should read "How much of the flour and butter mixture is needed?"

Comment: You have to show that it is now a single entity rather than two separate ingredients. Give it the proper identifier, if you will. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think I've realised you were right and was clutching at straws. Shouldn't it be "How much flour and butter are kneaded to make a pizza?" :)

Comment: "How much flour and butter are needed to make a pizza?" Kneaded is when you are pushing the dough together.

Comment: So...it would be "How much flour and butter are needed to make a pizza? You mix one cup of flower to 1/4 cup of melted butter. Mix the ingredients and knead the dough." (Don't take my measurements for granted. I made them up on the spot.)